# Azure Mobile Service, how to only update or ignore update some columns

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have got an item in the table and update some column value and update it into the DB.
But why this Datetimeoffset column is changed auto to another time zone ?

1. This is an item in DB

[image: Record at first time]

2. Using javascript backend to read and update it

```js
request.service.tables.getTable('Ticket')
.where({ id: ticketId }).read({
  systemProperties: ['__createdAt', '__updatedAt'],
  success: function (result) {
    if (result.length === 0) {
      console.log("ticket does not exist");
      response.send(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND, { message: "ticket does not exist" });
    }
    //Exists; update it
    else {
      // do update some column
      //...
      //...
      request.service.tables.getTable('Ticket').update(result[0]);
      }
```

3. I don't change the value of DatetimeOffset column, but it is changed.

[image]

How to I can ignore update it ?

Comment: There should be a Default Constraint on the table which updates the datetimeoffset value..check if this is the case with you..

Answer (score 1):

Basically, DateTimeOffset values are interpreted in the server side as JavaScript Date objects, and as such they don’t have any information about offsets (in JS dates are represented as a number of milliseconds since the “Unix 0”, 1970/01/01:00:00:00 UTC). The result was that the offset was lost in translation, and that was a problem.
=> So, the date time offset column should be in the UTC format.

I have found a post about this issue:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2013/05/13/preserving-date-time-offsets-in-azure-mobile-services/

Comment: Except to say, that blog post is for Azure Mobile Services and likely won't work on Azure Mobile Apps, since Azure Mobile Apps is a completely different codebase for the Node side of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the actual time values are equivalent, the first contain a time zone offset. You should be able to call ToLocalTime on the client to adjust the date back to local time (or whatever the equivalent is for you client platform).